# VB.net WinGrid EditButton Cell text not changing

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am working with Infragistics WinGrid (v17). I have WinGrid with a cell style of EditButton. I am trying to programmatically change the text of the value. See my `ClickCellButton` Handle Code below:

```
    Private Sub ugParameters_ClickCellButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs) Handles ugParameters.ClickCellButton
        Dim curRow As UltraGridRow
        If e.Cell.Column.Key = "ROWNAME" Then

            If ugParameters.Selected.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                curRow = ugParameters.Selected.Rows(0)
            Else
                curRow = ugParameters.ActiveRow
            End If
            curRow.Cells("SQLName").Value = "sdfsdf"
            'I also tried e.Cell.Value = "sdfsdf"
End Sub
```

This does not change the text in the cell.

NOTE: Just to be clear. I am NOT trying to change the button text, just the string inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what do you mean by the following:

> programmatically change the text of the value

Assuming you would like to change the value of the cell instead, that is part of the cell that button is being clicked on, you could do it like:

```
    If e.Cell.Column.Key = "ROWNAME" Then 
       e.Cell.Value = "New Value"
```

That would change the current cell value. If you would like to change another cells' value from the same row, you would do the following in the same event:

```
    If e.Cell.Column.Key = "ROWNAME" Then 
       e.Cell.Row.Cells("SQLName").Value = "Another Value"
```

Please also note, that those changes would occur only when the button you are clicking on is part of the cells that belong to the "ROWNAME" column.